# Generalized momentum in terms of wavefunction: Is it always $-i\hbar \partial/\partial q$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, harmonic-oscillator, commutator

I saw this kind of derivation several times in different notes/review/educational articles.
(For example https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.06560 or http://wcchew.ece.illinois.edu/chew/course/QMALL20121005.pdf)

We have a system such as a parallel LC circuit or an object in some sort of potential (often quadratic). We can choose a  variable we interpret as position $q$, get quantities we interpret as kinetic and potential energies, form a Lagrangian $\mathcal L(q,\dot q)$, then use definition of generalized momentum to figure out what the generalized momentum should be $p = \partial \mathcal L/\partial \dot{q}$ and form the Hamiltonian $\mathcal H(q,p) = p \dot q-\mathcal L$. Then we elevate $q$ and $p$ to be operators $\hat q$ and $\hat p$. The dynamics of the system is determined by the generalized Schrödinger equation: $\hat H |\psi\rangle = i \hbar \frac{\partial |\psi\rangle}{\partial t}$.

Summarizing what I have in mind is in the table below:

| System | Particle in potential $U(x)=kx^2$ | LC circuit (flux as position) | LC circuit (charge as position) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Position | Physical position $x$ | Flux in inductor $\Phi$ | Charge across capacitor $Q$ |
| Potential energy | $U(x)$ | $\frac1{2L} \Phi^2$ | $\frac1{2C} Q^2$ |
| Kinetic energy | $\frac12 m\dot x^2$ | $\frac12 C \dot{\Phi}^2$ | $\frac1{2} L\dot Q^2$ |
| Lagrangian | $m\dot x^2-U(x)$ | $\frac12 C \dot{\Phi}^2-\frac1{2L} \Phi^2$ | $\frac1{2} L\dot Q^2-\frac1{2C} Q^2$ |
| Generalized momentum | $m\dot x = p$ | $C \dot {\Phi} = Q$ | $L\dot Q = \Phi$ |
| Hamiltonian | $H(x,p) = \frac{p^2}{2m}+U(x)$ | $H(\Phi,Q)=\frac{Q^2}{2C}+\frac{\Phi^2}{2L}$ | $H(Q, \Phi) = \frac{\Phi^2}{2L}+\frac{Q^2}{2C}$ |
| Quantization | $\hat H = \frac{\hat p^2}{2m}+k \hat x^2$ | $H=\frac{\hat Q^2}{2C}+\frac{\hat{\Phi}^2}{2L}$ | $H = \frac{\hat{\Phi}^2}{2L}+\frac{\hat Q^2}{2C}$ |

So I understood this and I was trying to figure out how people know the energies of the quantum LC circuit and this is where my understanding falls short. For the particle in a potential $U(x)$, I've seen the solution in physics courses.
You write the Schrödinger equation in terms of position:
$\left(\frac{\hat p^2}{2m}+k \hat x^2\right) |\psi\rangle = i \hbar \frac{\partial |\psi\rangle}{\partial t} \rightarrow \left((-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x})^2+kx^2\right) \psi(x,t) = i \hbar \frac{\partial \psi(x,t)}{\partial t} $, at which point we just need to solve the partial differential equation. Here, momentum in terms of $\psi(x,t)$ was written as $-i \hbar \partial \psi/\partial x$. I understand that for a quantum LC circuit, we can think of $\psi(\Phi,t)$ if we want to treat $\Phi$ as position or we can think of $\psi(Q,t)$ if we treat $Q$ as position. What I am unsure is whether we can write conjugate momentum as

$-i \hbar \frac{\partial \Psi(\Phi,t)}{\partial \Phi}$ for the first case

and

$-i \hbar \frac{\partial \Psi(Q,t)}{\partial Q}$ for the second case.

The reason I am unsure is because every time I see LC quantum circuit, the next step is to write the Hamiltonian in terms of the creation and annihilation operators and reason towards saying what the energies are and what the separation between energies is. And I almost never see anyone try and use the approach that worked for the particle in a quadratic potential. So I'm wondering if maybe the generalized momentum can't be written as $-i\hbar \partial/\partial q$, except for the case where generalized position and momentum are the physical position and momentum. The only time I saw this done for LC circuit was here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_LC_circuit#Magnetic_Flux_as_a_Conjugate_Variable (though I admit to being new to quantum mechanics).

**So my question is this:**
If working with $\psi(q,t)$ where $q$ is generalized position, when is it that we can write the generalized momentum as $-i\hbar \partial \psi/\partial q$? Is it only in the case where $q$ is the physical position? Or can we use this for the quantum LC circuit (with $Q$ or $\Phi$ as the generalized momentum)? Can we also use it for any system that was quantized via the approach outlined above?

The reason I'm tempted to write momentum operator as $-i\hbar \partial/\partial q$ is because I know momentum and position operators need to satisfy the commutation relation, which I know is always valid for generalized position and its conjugate momentum:

$[\hat q, \hat p] = \hat q \hat p - \hat p \hat q = i\hbar \hat I$

and if we take $\hat p$ as $-i\hbar \partial \psi(q,t)/\partial q$, things works out very nicely:

$- i \hbar q \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial q} + i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial q}(q \psi) = i\hbar \psi$ (as expected)

But I also know that things working out nicely doesn't qualify as a proof. So I need some more confirmation.

Once again, I am new to quantum mechanics. So I apologize if I've butchered terminology. I will be sure to correct it based on the comments/answers.